# Taleo Client Connect Complex Query

Tags: taleo, taleo-connect-client

I'm building an export from requisitions from of Taleo using TCC (on windows); and want a boolean field to indicate if the job is an Evergreen one. Using the example in the TCC documentation guide i have been trying to find the right syntax for this query. The TCC editor insits this is invalid (as is posting the example straight from the [documentation](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/fusion-apps/tcclfp11b-userguide-enus-1647812.pdf). Do you have any suggestions on where i am going wrong?

```
<query alias="testGreatherThan" projectedClass="Requisition">
    <projections>
        <projection>
            <quer:string>true</quer:string>
        </projection>
    </projections>
    <filterings>
        <filtering>
            <greaterThan>
                <field path="JobInformation,Evergreen Req Number"/>
                <integer>1</integer>
            </greaterThan>
        </filtering>
    </filterings>
</query>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
<quer:query productCode="RC1704" model="http://www.taleo.com/ws/tee800/2009/01" alias="testGreatherThan" projectedClass="Requisition" locale="en" mode="CSV" xmlns:quer="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/query">
<quer:projections>
    <quer:projection>
        <quer:field path="ContestNumber"/>
    </quer:projection>
    <quer:projection alias="isEvergreen">
        <quer:decode>
            <quer:field path="JobInformation,Evergreen_20Req_20Number"/>
            <quer:string/>
            <quer:string>false</quer:string>
            <quer:string>true</quer:string>
        </quer:decode>
    </quer:projection>
</quer:projections>
<quer:filterings>
    <quer:filtering>
        <quer:equal>
            <quer:field path="State,Description"/>
            <quer:string>Sourcing</quer:string>
        </quer:equal>
    </quer:filtering>
</quer:filterings>
```

A few things to note:

- You need to have product integration pack 17.4 available (RC1704) to
  be able to open the script with TCC
- The script will export all requisitions having the "Sourcing" status,
  the second column will be a true/false flag. I used a "decode"
  function to generate it. If there is a value in "Evergreen Req
  Number", the flag will be set to true and it will be set to false
  otherwise
- Note that special characters need to be escaped when editing a TCC script with a text editor. You need to use an underscore (_) followed by the hexadecimal value of the character. If the field name is "Evergreen Req Number" you must escape the spaces: Evergreen_20Req_20Number. It is done automatically when editing a script in TCC.

Comment: Hi Stef, thanks for the response.; I have v17.8 do i need to downgrade? When i run the export with the decode in place i am getting the dreaded "A SAX parsing error occured during the removal of the SOAP envelope."

have also tried manually adding the decode into the projections list in the gui with the same script impact; and the same error when running the script.

Comment: Hi, please confirm that the field name in Taleo is really "Evergreen Req Number". The script is using the name, not the label. To get more details about the error you can uncheck "Fail on export error" in the "Strip SOAP" Post-processing step of your configuration file.

Comment: OK, issue was the blank string, this decode returns the right answer
    <quer:projection alias="Is_Evergreen">
      <quer:decode>
        <quer:field path="JobInformation,Evergreen_20Req_20Number"/>
        <quer:string>true</quer:string>
        <quer:string>false</quer:string>
      </quer:decode>
    </quer:projection